# Do I need to learn nx for backend?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I started learning backend on Node.js. I recently completed a course on [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/). Now I’m watching a course on microservices and nx is used for monorepo. Should I go through monorepo and nx?

As I understand it, `npx create-nx-workspace --preset=nest` creates a monorepo. Monorepo is needed to store the entire project in one repository, but is this often used and is such project storage relevant or is it not worth spending time on this and it’s better to start learning multirepo?

After creating a project via `npx create-nx-workspace --preset=nest`, I had quite a lot of folders that I had not worked with before. As I understand, they are intended for creating a fullstack application. Do I need to study this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Here is an opinion you should consider:***

Whether or not you should learn Nx and monorepos depends on your specific needs and goals.

If you are working on a small project or are not familiar with microservices, then you may not need to learn Nx.

However, if you are working on a large project or are interested in microservices, then learning Nx can be a valuable investment.

**Monorepos can provide several benefits, including:**

1. Increased code sharing: Monorepos make it easy to share code between different parts of your application. This can help to reduce code duplication and make it easier to maintain your codebase.
2. Improved tooling: Nx provides a number of tools that can help you to manage and develop your monorepo. These tools can help you to automate tasks, such as building and testing your code.
3. Simplified dependency management: Monorepos can simplify dependency management by making it easier to track and update dependencies across your entire codebase.

**However, monorepos can also have some drawbacks, including:**

1. Increased complexity: Monorepos can be more complex to manage than multirepos. This is especially true if your monorepo is large or if you have a lot of different teams working on it.
2. Increased build times: Building a monorepo can take longer than building a multirepo. This is because a monorepo contains all of your code, which means that you need to build all of your code every time you make a change.
3. Increased risk of breaking changes: Making a breaking change in a monorepo can have a larger impact than making a breaking change in a multirepo. This is because a breaking change in a monorepo can break other parts of your application that depend on it.
   Ultimately, the decision of whether or not to use a monorepo is a trade-off. The benefits of monorepos can outweigh the drawbacks for some projects, but not for others.

If you are not sure whether or not you should use a monorepo, I suggest starting with a multirepo and then switching to a monorepo if you find that it is necessary. This will give you the flexibility to switch between monorepos and multirepos as needed.

As for the folders you saw when you created your project with npx create-nx-workspace --preset=nest, these folders are part of the Nx ecosystem. Nx is a tool that helps you to manage monorepos. The folders you saw contain the code for the Nx tools, as well as the code for your application.

You do not need to study all of the Nx tools in order to use Nx. However, it is a good idea to familiarize yourself with the tools that you are most likely to use. This will help you to get the most out of Nx.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This answer looks like a copy -paste from ChatGPT

Comment: Re *"an opinion you should consider"*: Is it [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)'s (or similar) opinion?